# Use Input "Id" instead of Input "Name"

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I managed to get a text input and select box to updated based off of the input box using some javascript....but we changed our form variables so I can no longer use the input "name"...I now need to use the id.  How can i alter my javascript to use the id t do what Im currently doing?

jsp:

```
TAMCN:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="tamcn" name="tamcn"  value=""  size="6" maxlength="5" onkeyup="javascript:tamcnSearchUpdated(this.value,'detSearchForm')" onkeypress="javascript:return noenter();" autocomplete="off" />
    <select id="tamcnList"  name="filterCriteria('TAMCN').values" onchange="javascript:this.form.tamcn.value = '';">
    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
    <c:forEach var="tamcn" items="${tamcns}"><option value="${tamcn.code}">${tamcn.code}</option></c:forEach>
</select>
```

javascript:

```
  function tamcnSearchUpdated(tamcn, formName)
    {
        var tamcnUpper = tamcn.toUpperCase();
        document.forms[formName].elements.tamcn.value = tamcnUpper;

        var len = tamcn.length;
        if ( tamcnUpper.indexOf('*') >= 0 )
        {
            document.forms[formName].elements['tamcnList'].options[0].selected = 'selected';
            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[formName].elements['tamcnList'].options.length; i++)
        {
            if (document.forms[formName].elements['tamcnList'].options[i].text.substr(0,len) == tamcnUpper)
            {
                document.forms[formName].elements['tamcnList'].options[i].selected = 'selected';
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is not the first time I removed `[jsp]` tag from your pure JavaScript related question. In the future pure JS related questions, you don't need to tag JSP (or any other server side view technology). The problem has got nothing to do with JSP as it's just a HTML-generator. JavaScript doesn't run in server, but in client (the webbrowser). The client is not in any way aware of the server side view technology used.

Comment: oh my bad...I thought because its jsp code in addition to javascript code...I should put the proper tags

Comment: One time...I placed javascript in the tag...and some guys wrote..."hey is that PHP or something????"...lol

Comment: Think about this: would you have exactly the same problem when you used plain vanilla HTML? If so, then the problem is not related to the view technology used. It's also preferable to formulate the question in plain HTML context (so ignore the JSP code and take its generated HTML output as example instead).

Comment: thanks my friend...you have guided me like a light tower in the storm!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).

So, instead of

```
document.forms[formName].elements['tamcnList']
```

write

```
document.getElementById('tamcnList')
```

You may want to assign it to a variable instead of repeating it everytime. Keep your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

#### See also:

- [Mozilla Developer Network - JavaScript tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide)

Comment: ...instead of "document.forms['some'].elements[name]"

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('tamcnList').options[0].selected;
```

However, remember that IDs must be unique across the whole page. If you've got other `id="tamcnList"` elements in the page, this will fail and you'll most likely get the WRONG element.